# Expo StatusBar style

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to set the style of StatusBar to "light", so the colors of the battery and clock will be white.

This is what I'm doing:

```
import { Slot } from "expo-router";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { SafeAreaView, SafeAreaProvider } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import theme from "../utils/theme";

export default function Layout() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <Slot />
        <StatusBar style="light" />
      </SafeAreaView>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: theme.background,
  },
});
```

Now the thing is that, after i add that line,  the color of the icons is changed to white.
But after i hit r(reload app) the color is reverted to default black.

Why is this happening? Thanks for answers.

Comment: Note that i use Expo router for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by adding this to app.json

```
"userInterfaceStyle": "dark"
```

Hope it helps somebody.

Comment: I didn't reproduce the problem， but
In the project I initialized, app.json "userInterfaceStyle": "light", 
Maybe deletion is another way